# WSRP URL rewriting in JBoss Portal 2.7.2

Tags: jboss, url-rewriting, portal, producer, wsrp

Does anyone know if WSRP URL rewriting is supported in Jboss Portal 2.7.2 when acting as a producer?

Currently, the URL rewriting is done on the consumer, which has to parse the mark-up (returned from Jboss) to find special WSRP tokens. This can have a performance impact, which can be improved by supplying the URLs directly to the producer (Jboss in our case).

Regards,
Jonathan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Answer can be found here: http://community.jboss.org/message/587434